# BigQueryTable.InsertRows throws Table xx not found intermittingly

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

We are simply deleting table, creating table and then inserting data using,

```
        BigQueryTable table;
        try
        {
            table = dataset.GetTable(tableName);
            table.Delete();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            table = dataset.CreateTable(tableName, schemaBuilder.Build());
        }

        table.InsertRows(rows);
```

It works but sometimes it throws,

```
Exception while executing function: BigQueryExport Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Table xxxx not found. [404]
Errors [
    Message[Table xxxx not found.] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]

exception Google.GoogleApiException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1+<ParseResponse>d__31.MoveNext (Google.Apis, Version=1.49.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute (Google.Apis, Version=1.49.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab)
   at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClientImpl.InsertRows (Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0)
```

We are using `google.cloud.bigquery.v2` version `2.1.0`.

Comment: This might be an expected behavior of the API. See **Table Creation/Deletion** part in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#metadata-errors-for-streaming-inserts

Comment: Yeah I saw that but what is the solution

Comment: Are you deleting then creating the same table name and schema? Or are you creating a new table whenever the code runs?

Comment: Yea, its like lot of new existing data. The easiest solution is delete all data and create new one

Comment: Apologies, it seems that my previous question is wrong or too general. Just want to confirm if the table that you are creating has a different name, compared to the previously deleted table? (Case 1. Delete table1, create table2, insert rows to table2) Or is it (Case 2. Delete table1, create table1, insert rows to table1)?

Comment: The table name is same whether you call it table 1 or table2. Table deleted(drop in traditional term), create table with same name and insert new rows to newly created table

Comment: @RiccoD just to add also ask the same question at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/8146

There one recommendation is to retry. What you suggest?

Comment: I see. Retry is probably the best solution for this to cover the APIs limitations. A similar I also found a similar [git issue for go lang](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/975#issuecomment-1005667179) and their solution is to introduce a delay prior to inserting rows which is similar to your solution.

Comment: Since you found a solution, you can post it as an answer and accept it. Just so other users in the future can easily see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since table creation is eventual consistent, I have added retry option during inserting rows like,

```
         var policy = Policy
            .Handle<GoogleApiException>()
            .WaitAndRetry(new[]
            {
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            })
            .Execute(() => table.InsertRows(rows));
```

There are some more way to fix this as mention here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/8146