# Google BigQuery (C#): Table not found after creating table when using InsertRows sometimes

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I am working on a project which uses C# .NET5 and Google Big Query to read a CSV file and insert the CSV data into GBQ. However, I got the error:

```
Errors [
    Message[Table 702873453552:my_dataset.my_table not found.] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
```

The code I used to create table and insert rows are from google official website:

1. Create table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-create-table#bigquery_create_table-csharp
2. InsertRows:
   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows

   ```
   var table = new BigQueryCreateTable(schema, tableId);
                        table.CreateTable();
     using (CsvReader csvr = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        {
            csvr.Read();
            csvr.ReadHeader();
            var bigQueryTableInsertRows = new BigQueryTableInsertRows(tableId, projectId);
            string[] headerRowItems = csvr.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord;
            var i = 0;
            ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();
            while (csvr.Read())
            {
                var key = "";
                var value = "";
                var j = 0;

                var bigQueryRow = new BigQueryInsertRow($"{i}")
                while (j < headerRowItems.Length)
                {
                    key = headerRowItems[j];
                    value = csvr.GetField<string>(headerRowItems[j]);
                    bigQueryRow.Add(key, value);
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
                rows.Add(bigQueryRow);
            }
            var rowArr = rows.ToArray(typeof(BigQueryInsertRow)) as BigQueryInsertRow[];
            **bigQueryTableInsertRows.TableInsertRows(rowArr);**
        }
   ```

Sometimes, it will not find the table and throw the error. However, it does not happen all the time. Just sometimes.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71131873/bigquerytable-insertrows-throws-table-xx-not-found-intermittingly ?

Comment: Did you happen to solve the issue by following the stack thread mentioned by @RiccoD.?

Comment: Hi @SayanBhattacharya, yeah. RiccoD 's post works perfectly for me. I put the Policy.WaitAndRetry in a catch block, specifically handle this issue. Thanks a lot!